# Example for custom Range in Gtkmm

Tags: gtkmm

I am working on a Potentiometer style widget in Gtkmm and I'd like to use Range as the baseclass.

Does anyone know of a proper example for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking for.  I know that there is a simple example of using the range widget [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/3.0/sec-range-example.html.en).  It does handle the creation of the Adjustment object that you'll need.  You'll need to define an abstract potentiometer class, then create your vertical and/or horizontal potentiometers separately for flexibility.

The closest thing that I could find to an example of what you'd need to override in order to make your own custom range-like widget is on [Old Nabble](http://old.nabble.com/Customizing-scrollbar-in-a-ScrolledWindow-td24360834.html).

I wish that I could give you more help with this, but I'm rather new to Gtkmm.